# Событие происходит только при повторном нажатии

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет, у меня есть такой код:

```
$(function editCheckbox () {
    checked = true;
    $(document).on('click', '.true', function () { 
        if (checked) {
            $(this).attr('src', '../assets/img/checkbox_active.jpg');
            $(this).addClass('thisActive');
            checked = false;
        } else {
            $(this).attr('src', '../assets/img/checkbox_disabled.jpg');
            $(this).removeClass('thisActive');
            checked = true;
        } 
    })
});
```

У меня есть объекты `img` с классом `true`. Если взять любую из них и нажать, то событие происходит с 1 клика по объекту, а таких объектов 4 и если на какой-то объект уже нажали, то чтобы событие произошло на других, нужно нажимать 2 раза. Как это исправить?

Comment: У вас одна переменная(глобальная) checked на все объекты. А нужно каждому объекту своё состояние где-то хранить.

Comment: Можно использовать `$(this).hasClass('thisActive')` для проверки состояния, а переменную checked вообще убрать.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click', '.true', function () { 
    if (!$(this).hasClass('thisActive')) {

        $(this).attr('src', '../assets/img/checkbox_active.jpg');
        $(this).addClass('thisActive');
    } else {
        $(this).attr('src', '../assets/img/checkbox_disabled.jpg');
        $(this).removeClass('thisActive');
    } 
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9uo6ztjd/1/